# Do Java programs natively support the concept of version?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering if there is any standard procedure to set a Java project's version (a bit like a Windows executable file version).

I'd like to have my application's code able to have introspection capabilities so it can know its own version.

Is it possible, at all, to do this with Java without resorting to have a .txt file in the directory with the version as contents?

If yes, the ideal would be to have Eclipse update the version each time it is compiled. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java native way to store version information is in the [manifest files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) ([this part of the tutorial is about version information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html)).

You can use [the `Package` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html) and its methods such as [`getImplementationVersion`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationVersion%28%29) to get at those details at runtime.

Comment: Do manifest files work even if my project isn't deployed as a JAR file?

Comment: @devouredelysium: no, but in that case I'd say you're running a development version anyway, which is a special case.

Comment: I see. But this actually is a deal breaker for me, as most of the time when running this, I'll be in development mode and a large part of my program depends on this (it isn't that good of an idea to have a method for development mode and another to production mode, I know unexpected weird stuff could end up happening in the latter). I'll have to stick to .txt files then? I'm not sure how to tell Eclipse that I want it to create a .txt file in a given place each time it automatically builds a .java file, though..

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure how to tell Eclipse that I want it to create a .txt file in a given place each time it automatically builds a .java file, though..

Can I suggest that you take a look at Maven, and the release process that it supports.